# @Published Bool never updates to true

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI App. Below is my code for an observalbleObject view model

```
class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: LoginViewModel
    @Published var productList = ProductApiData(results: [])
    @Published var success = false
    func getProducts(_ params: String...) {
        ProductApi().getProducts(sessionId: params[0], status: params[1], searchText: params[2], completion: { result, data in
                if result == .success {
                   guard let data = data else { return }
                  
                    let decodedResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ProductApiData.self, from: data as! Data)
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        self.productList = decodedResponse
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    func updateProduct (_ params: String...) {
        ProductApi().updateProduct(sessionId: params[0], parentProductAsin: params[1], productTitle: params[2], parentCategory: params[3], productCateogry: params[4], productTeam: params[5], productSubCategory: params[6], carouselProduct: params[7], featuredProduct: params[8], isHot: params[9], isNew: params[10], numReviews: params[11], rating: params[12], productPrice: params[13], productImagePath: params[14], completion: { result, data in
                if result == .success {
                    
                    guard let data = data else { return }
                   
                    let decodedResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ApiCallData.self, from: data as! Data)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        if decodedResponse.success{
                            self.success = true
                            print("!")
                          
                        
                        }
                       
                 }
                }
            
            })
    }
}
```

Below is the code for my view

```
    import Foundation

import SwiftUI

struct ProductInformationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var quantityViewModel: QuantityViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var orderItemViewModel: OrderItemViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: LoginViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var productViewModel: ProductViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var orderItemViewModlel: OrderItemViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var orderViewModel: OrderViewModel
    @StateObject var localNotification = LocalNotification()

    @State var product: Product



    @State private var initalQuantity = "0"

    @State private var datePickerSelection = Date()
    let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {

        Form {
            Group {
                HStack {
                    Text("Parent Asin")
                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", text: $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].parentProductAsin).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Product Asin")
                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", text: $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productAsin).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }
                TextEditor(text: $product.productTitle)
                Picker(selection: $product.parentCategory, label: Text("Parent Category")) {
                    ForEach(["Maryland", "Terps", "MLB", "NFL"], id: \.self) {
                        Text($0).tag($0)
                    }
                }
                Picker(selection: $product.productTeam, label: Text("Product Team")) {
                    ForEach(["Maryland", "Orioles", "Yankees", "Tampa Bay", "NA"], id: \.self) {
                        Text($0).tag($0)
                    }
                }


                Picker(selection: $product.productCategory, label: Text("Product Category")) {
                    ForEach(["Clothing", "HeadWear", "Footwear", "Socks", "Accessories", "Automobile","ShotGlass","Decals and Magnets"], id: \.self) {
                        Text($0).tag($0)
                    }
                }
                Picker(selection: $product.productSubCategory, label: Text("Product Sub Category")) {
                    ForEach(["Kids", "Mens", "Women", "Unisex", "Youth", "Toddler", "Infant", "License Plate","Decal"], id: \.self) {
                        Text($0).tag($0)
                    }
                }

                HStack {
                    Text("Number of Reviews")

                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", value: $product.numReviews, formatter: NumberFormatter()).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Rating")

                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", value: $product.rating, formatter: NumberFormatter()).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }
            }
            Group {
                Toggle(isOn: $product.isHotProduct) {
                    Text("Is Hot")
                }

                Toggle(isOn: $product.featuredProduct) {
                    Text("Is Featured")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $product.carouselProduct) {
                    Text("Is Carousel")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $product.isNewProduct) {
                    Text("Is New")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Box Number")

                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", text: $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productBoxNumber).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Product Image Path")

                    Spacer()
                    if (product.productHasVariations == true) {

                    } else {
                        TextField("", text: $product.productImagePath).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }
                    /*if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {

                        TextField("", text: .bindOptional($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productImagePath, "")).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)

                    }*/

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Product Price")

                    Spacer()
                    if (product.productHasVariations == true) {

                    } else {
                        TextField("", value: $product.productPrice, formatter: formatter).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }
                    /*if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        
                            TextField("", text: .bindOptional($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productPrice, "") ).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        
                    }*/

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Total Quantity")

                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", value: $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].totalQuantity, formatter: NumberFormatter()).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Sold Quantity")

                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", value: $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].soldQuantity, formatter: NumberFormatter()).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("In-Stock Quantity")

                    Spacer()
                    if ($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results.count == 0) {
                        TextField("", text: $initalQuantity).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        TextField("", value: $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].inStockQuantity, formatter: NumberFormatter()).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                }

            }
            Button("Update") {
                
                updateProductInformation {
                    
                }
                     /*updateQuantityInformation()
                        
                    updateOrderItemInformation()
                    updateOrderInformation()
                    localNotification.setLocalNotification(title: product.productTitle, subtitle: product.productAsin, body: "asd", when: 5)
*/            }
        }.onAppear(perform: setQuantityInformation)
    }
    func setQuantityInformation() {

        self.quantityViewModel.getQuantities(self.viewModel.user.token!, "PARENT", product.productAsin)

    }

    func updateProductInformation(finished: () ->Void ) {
        print("@1")
        self.productViewModel.updateProduct(self.viewModel.user.token!,
            $product.productAsin.wrappedValue,
            $product.productTitle.wrappedValue,
            $product.parentCategory.wrappedValue,
            $product.productCategory.wrappedValue,
            $product.productTeam.wrappedValue,
            $product.productSubCategory.wrappedValue,
            String($product.carouselProduct.wrappedValue),
            String($product.featuredProduct.wrappedValue),
            String($product.isHotProduct.wrappedValue),
            String($product.isNewProduct.wrappedValue),
            String($product.numReviews.wrappedValue),
            String($product.rating.wrappedValue),
            String($product.productPrice.wrappedValue),
            $product.productImagePath.wrappedValue)
        print($productViewModel.success.wrappedValue)
        if($productViewModel.success.wrappedValue) {
            print("@2")
            updateQuantityInformation()
            print("@3")
        }
        print($productViewModel.success.wrappedValue)
        

    }
    func updateQuantityInformation() {
        self.quantityViewModel.updateQuantities(self.viewModel.user.token!,
            $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productAsin.wrappedValue,
            String($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].totalQuantity.wrappedValue),
            String($quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].inStockQuantity.wrappedValue),
            $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productBoxNumber.wrappedValue,
            "", "", "", $product.productTitle.wrappedValue)



    }

    func updateOrderItemInformation() {
        self.orderItemViewModel.updateOrderItem(self.viewModel.user.token!,
            $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productAsin.wrappedValue,
            $quantityViewModel.quantityList.results[0].productBoxNumber.wrappedValue,
            $product.productImagePath.wrappedValue,
            String($product.productPrice.wrappedValue))
        

    }

    func updateOrderInformation() {

        self.orderViewModel.updateOrder(sessionId: self.viewModel.user.token!,
            orderItems: $orderItemViewModel.orderItemsListIds.wrappedValue)
    }
}
```

Clicking the update button on my view calls a  function updateProductInformation which in return calls an API to update the information. As part of the above function I have

```
if($productViewModel.success.wrappedValue) {
            print("@2")
            updateQuantityInformation()
            print("@3")
        }
```

Everytime I run this the observedvariable is always false but i am sure I am updating it as part of the observable object. Any idea why is this happening

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "updates to true". You have a variable `Published var success = false`. I don't see any code that sets it to `true` so how is supposed to "update"?

Comment: @matt The below code in the observable object ProductViewModel 
 updates it to a true DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        if decodedResponse.success{
                            self.success = true
                            print("!")
                          
                        
                        }

Comment: Good answer! Could it be that we're not grappling with the fact that this happens asynchronously? The idea of an observable object is that it _notifies_ you when something changes. Or you could _subscribe_ directly to a publishable value. But it isn't supposed to be something you just _look_ at.

Comment: Any solutions to resolve it or change the code so that I can have it to true. because of this my code after the updateproductinformation never gets run

Comment: EnvironmentObjects only work inside a SwiftUI Views that are struct. Not a class

Comment: Also all of those wrappedValues are unnecessary. Just remove the $ binding is only needed as a two way connection.

Comment: @loremipsum what's the best way to deal with it then, any tutorials or references u can give me. I followed a tutorial to accomplish this.

Comment: Your API calls are asynchronous too you can’t expect to have access to the result of the call on the very next line.

Comment: Apple SwiftUI Tutorials and the Meet async/await video from one of the WWDCs. There are many issues, I am not saying just to be annoying.

Comment: @user3509208 whatever tutorial that taught you this is wrong. Don’t use them… ever.

Comment: Got it. I will look through the Apple Swiftui Tuts. and Meet async await

Comment: Trashing the code now, want to write it the right WAY.

Comment: @loremipsum https://github.com/sminrana/swiftui-login/tree/main/SwiftUI%20Login/SwiftUI%20Login here is the link I am(was) following

Comment: That code doesn’t look bad. There are some styling issues and practices I wouldn’t  recommend. Your code has some basic issues that stem from misinterpretations of what is going on. There are common issues with people just starting out. I see these issues all the time on SO. It is just so much there is no way to help with more detail I. Is forum.